# Add empty string if regex matches consecutive delimiters

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I am working on a case where I want to convert the data from string to arrays based on delimiters. In the below example I have `|` as a delimiter and I want to convert it into a array of values.

It works fine in ideal case. But in case if there is consecutive delimiters (As you can see in 3rd line `v3|v3||v3|v3`). I want to add `null` or `empty string` to to the  array.

How can I add null value when I find two consecutive delimiters.

```js
const data = `
h1|h2|h3|h4|h5
v1|v1|v1|v1|v1
v2|v2|v2|v2|v2
v3|v3||v3|v3
`;
const lines = data.trim().split(/\n/g);
const result = lines.map(line => line.trim().split(/\|+/g));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Remove `+`, use `split('|')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the + from your regex

```js
const data = `
h1|h2|h3|h4|h5
v1|v1|v1|v1|v1
v2|v2|v2|v2|v2
v3|v3||v3|v3
`;
const lines = data.trim().split(/\n/g);
const result = lines.map(line => line.trim().split('|'));
console.log(result);
```